# Will a bankruptcy always show up in a basic pre-employment background check?

Tags: job-search

Is there a time frame when a bankruptcy won't show in a general background check in Colorado? I now have good credit, no criminal history, an excellent driving record and just came off a 13 year high profile job in a law firm with excellent references.  I filed bankruptcy in 1998.  Will a pre-employment ackground check always show this?  If it does, should I tell the potential employer up front and try to talk about it?

Comment: Look in Section 605 of the [Fair Credit Reporting Act](http://www.ftc.gov/os/statutes/031224fcra.pdf) to see when a bankruptcy might come off your credit report.  As to what constitutes a "basic" background check, I don't think there's one answer -- depends on the industry, company, state, etc.  Some places will do a credit check as a matter of course, some won't.

Comment: The form you fill out should state the time frame for each section. Some may go back decades, others only a few years. Always err on divulging a little too much vs assuming they won't care if I fib in this section.